# Extbase: Choose lazy or eager loading at runtime

Tags: orm, lazy-loading, typo3, extbase

I have a domain object Foo that has an 1:n relation to a domain object Bar.

There are two major use cases where I need to get all foo's matching some criterion. In case A, I care about the bars attached to each foo, in case B, I don't. There are quite a lot of bars, so simply always loading the bars is not good for performance of case A. Similarly, not loading the bars eagerly will lead to an n+1 avalanche in case B. So neither tagging the realtion as @Lazy nor not tagging it is the correct choice.

Now, my question: Is it possible to tell the extbase persistence layer at query time whether to be lazy or eager? If yes, how? If no, is there another way in Extbase to avoid the n+1 problem (i.e. load all necessary bars and then hope that caching works when iterating through the foos)?

My last resort, of course, would be to load the foos with lazy loading, load the bars manually in a second query, and then manually set the relation.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I solved it by redesigning case B to work on the foos individually. Not nice, but better, and fast enough for the time being. I still would like how to achieve this.

Comment: Can you answer your own question and then mark ist as solved? It still pops up in the list of unsanswered [typo3] questions.

Comment: Hm... I don't really think the question has been answered. I found a workaround for this particular problem, but the general case...

Comment: Alright. I understand your first comment now.

Comment: How about doing a SQL query and then manually map rows to objects using PropertyMapper?

Comment: Doing a SQL query and return raw result, I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been playing around with Extbase and delving into the internals in the last few months, and the upshot is this: It' impossible.

I suppose that closes this question, though not the way I'ld like.

Actually, even worse: Eager loading is not implemented at all, the @eager tag which according to the documentation sets eager loading for a relation is ignored.

Comment: For the last part: Eager loading is the default, hence there is no `@eager` Tag. You can just change this behaviour to lazy with the `@lazy` Tag.

Comment: @shredding That would not make it possible to chose between lazy or eager behaviour at runtime, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yeah, you can't set it at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

what about leaving it lazy and converting it to an array when needed? (foo->bar->toArray())

Comment: What are the benefits of doing this?

Comment: That would still be lazy (extra DB query at usage time to get missing data, one query for each item) instead of eager (all necessary data is loaded from the db by the single, initial query)